# Check to see if date is not in between

Tags: sql, vb.net

I am using vb.net.

I have a database set with following table and three columns. So user can add their event start date/time and end date/time.

```
Table = "Eventable"
|----|------------------------|-----------------------|
| ID | StartBy                | EndBy                 |
|----|------------------------|-----------------------|
| 1  | 7/1/2015 2:30:00 PM    | 7/1/2015 4:00:00 PM   |
| 2  | 1/22/2013 8:00:00 AM   | 1/22/2013 3:00:00 PM  |
| 3  | 10/22/2014 10:25:00 AM | 10/22/2014 6:20:00 PM |
| 4  | 4/5/2010 5:00:00 PM    | 4/5/2010 8:00:00 PM   | 
| 5  | 7/3/2015 12:00:00 PM   | 77/2/2015 8:00:00 PM  |
|----|------------------------|-----------------------|
```

The user will next enter a new `StartBy` Event from `textbox(7/1/2015 3:00:00 PM)`:

```
Dim getNewStartEventDateTime As String = getNewStartEventDateTimeTB.Text
```

Then the user will enter a new `EndBy` Event from `textbox(7/1/2015 7:00:00 PM)`:

```
Dim getNewEndEventDateTime As String = getNewEndEventDateTimeTB.Text
```

Now, how can I write a query that will test to see if the new event is not between the database timing? In other words, a test to see if the new event timing isn't taken.

**This is what I have so far.**

```
Dim query As String = "SELECT * FROM Eventable WHERE StartBy not Between #" & getNewStartEventDateTime.Text & "# AND  #" & getNewEndEventDateTime.Text & ";"

If error then
  // Error - This time is taken. Please enter a different time. 
else
  // No errors - Add a new event
end if
```

Comment: Did you mean exact timing or overlapping as well?

Answer (score 0):

Try the below query:

```
SELECT * FROM Eventable 
where EndBy                  < '"& getNewStartEventDateTime .Text &"'
or StartBy                 > '"& getNewEndEventDateTime  & "'
```

[**Query using between**](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_between.asp) :

```
 SELECT * FROM Eventable WHERE StartBy not Between '" & getNewStartEventDateTime .Text & "' AND  '" & getNewEndEventDateTime  &"';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
Dim query As String = "SELECT * FROM Eventable WHERE StartBy not Between '" & getNewStartEventDateTime .Text & "' AND  '" & getNewEndEventDateTime  & "';"
```